# Error Model on id gate, is not giving any error

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, noise

I am trying to play with `NoiseModel` of `qiskit`, and I noticed that error on id gate is not giving any error results, while error on the measurement (or other gates) does give an error:

```
def get_noise_model(p_err):
    error_gate1 = pauli_error([("X", p_err / 2), ("Z", p_err / 2), ("I", 1 - p_err)])
    noise_model = NoiseModel()
    noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_gate1, "id")
    print(error_gate1)
    return noise_model

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.id(0)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

results = (execute(qc,Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator"),noise_model=get_noise_model(0.2),shots=2048).result().get_counts())

plot_histogram(results)
```

Histogram:
[image]

And changing to :

```
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_gate1, "measure")
```

gives that:
[image]

Why is that happening? If I perform noisy `id` gate

imports needed:

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise.errors import pauli_error
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute , Aer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `execute` function sets `optimization_level` value to $1$ which leads to some optimizations such as removing ID gates.

Just set `optimization_level` to $0$ to override this behavior:

```
results = (execute(qc,Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator"),noise_model=get_noise_model(0.2),optimization_level=0,shots=2048).result().get_counts())
```

The result should look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked